# Android Unit Test local native library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find so file

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-ndk

I run a android test for my project which its apply is `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` .But UnsatisfiedLinkError occurred:

```
java 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.yzd.unikeysdk.test-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yzd.unikeysdk.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libsotpcomm.so"
```

there is my `build.gradle`:

[image]

[image]

```
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['.jar', '.so'])
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I removed

```
   sourceSets {
   main {
       jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
  }
```

from my `build.gradle`.
What's more, I move so file from `libs/lib/armeabi/libsotpcomm.so` to `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi`. Then I run the unit test and found that the problem was sloved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnoDe.png)